# Annotating a cartodb torque timeline-control

Tags: carto, torque

I'd like to know what options there are to customise a cartodb torque timeline control.
I've seen awesome visualisations made with CartoDB/Torque for FIFA '14 matches by twitterdata ( for instance http://cartodb.com/v/worldcup/match/?TC=x&vis=31ed2e2a-06ce-11e4-8c1d-0e230854a1cb&h=t&t=Brazil,FFCC00%7CGermany,B40903&m=7%2F8%2F2014%2017:00:00%20GMT,7%2F8%2F2014%2018:52:00GMT&g=108%7C11,23,24,26,29,87,97#/2/-17.6/-5.6/0 ).

From trying to read that code I inferred that twitter data created a modified Torque to do just that.

Before going in that direction, what are the best ways to customise Torque Timeline controls?

What I specifically want to achieve is have a graph displayed above the timeline that 'guides' the user as to when events happen.
In this example: https://emileaben.cartodb.com/viz/6a6d789c-8430-11e4-a483-0e4fddd5de28/public_map , there is an event at around 7:32 CEST (lots of red dots in the US, representing Internet connectivity going down), and having a graph with number of events over time, on the timeline axis would really help guide users to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the FIFA 14 Torque map was created using Twitter data. [CartoDB can import data directly from Twitter api](http://cartodb.com/solutions/twitter-maps/).

About Torque with graphs, you can check a great example in this [**link**](http://mwcimpact.com/).

Also, I would like to suggest you another great tool to create stories: [Odyssey](http://cartodb.github.io/odyssey.js/)